# How to do to delete undefined offset 0 in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building app in laravel and when somebody doesn't have fill their data I get undefined offset 0.

Now I am doing something like this to skip that:

```
Sex: @if($user->user_data[0]->sex == 0) <br />@else {{$user->user_data[0]->sex}}<br /> @endif
```

But what is the easiest way to do it?

Controller:

```
$user = $this->model->getUserById($id);

if(!$user){ 
    abort(404);
}

return view('user.user', compact('user'));
```

Model:

```
$user = User::with('user_data', 'comments')->where('id', $id)->first();

return $user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a count before you go into the user_data

```
@if($user->user_data->count())
    Sex: @if($user->user_data[0]->sex == 0) <br />@else {{$user->user_data[0]->sex}}<br /> @endif
@endif
```

Comment: That's the same. Another idea?

Comment: Just to try something, what do you get if you do `Log::info($user->user_data);` and look in your log file?

Comment: And is `user_data` a one-to-many, or a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Try `@if($user->user_data->count() != 0)`, but definitely check and see what the log contains.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Sex: {!! (isset($user->user_data[0]) ) ? (($user->user_data[0]->sex == 0) ? ' <br />' : $user->user_data[0]->sex) : '<br />' !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ternary operator`:

```
Sex: {{ ( $user->user_data[0]->sex ? $user->user_data[0]->sex : 'Not Found' ) }}
```

Or shorthand usage

```
Sex: {{ ( $user->user_data[0]->sex ?: 'Not Found' ) }}

//  means
//  if($user->user_data[0]->sex){
//      echo $user->user_data[0]->sex;
//  }
//  else{
//      echo 'Not Found';
//  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Sex: @if(isset($user->user_data[0])) 
        {{$user->user_data[0]->sex ?: ''}}
     @endif
<br />
```